# Does it make sense to put a unique constraint on a nullable soft-delete flag?

Tags: database-design, unique-constraint, db2-midrange

So we currently have the following:

```
MYTABLE
COLUMN: ID (INTEGER Primary key, auto-incrementer)
COLUMN: START (DATE)
COLUMN: COMPANYID (INTEGER, Foreign key to COMPANY)
COLUMN: DELETED (INTEGER)
CHECK: DELETED = 0 OR DELETED = 1
```

Now, there's the requirement to allow infinite deleted records, but to only allow a single non-deleted record for each date+company.

I suggested to change the schema to:

```
MYTABLE
COLUMN: ID (INTEGER Primary key, auto-incrementer)
COLUMN: START (DATE)
COLUMN: COMPANYID (INTEGER, Foreign key to COMPANY)
COLUMN: ACTIVE (Nullable INTEGER)
CHECK: ACTIVE = 1 OR ACTIVE IS NULL
UNIQUE: START, COMPANYID, ACTIVE
```

While my coworker is of the opinion that that is "going too far with constraints" and that we should just rely on the uniqueness checking in the application.

Is there a generally accepted best practice here?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ That seems much nicer, but a quick search suggests db2 doesn't support, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sarov, does your version of Db2 support generated columns? There seem to be something wrong with IBM:s site(s) at the moment, so I can't check for my self

Comment: @Lennart I believe it does. Why?

Comment: @sarov, see my edit below. The idea is to generate a column where the generated value is same as the p.k. when active is null, when it is not null active is used. Therefore you can have as many null values as you wish, but only one real value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what DBMS you are referring to, but your suggested unique constraint won't work for several out there, because null is not equal to null

```
create table t (x int not null, y int, unique(x,y));
insert into t (x) values (1);
insert into t (x) values (1);

Postgres12
Does not violate the constraint

Oracle18c
Violates constraint

Db2 Developer C 11.1
Does not accept nullable columns in unique constraint

Firebird 3.0
Violates constraint

MariaDB 10.4
Does not violate the constraint

MySQL 8.0
Does not violate the constraint

SQLlite 3.27
Does not violate the constraint

SQLServer 2017
Violates constraint
```

Tested at [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef69a6da6f1267b7cb7e2a03918a9abf)

So, generally speaking, your UNIQUE constraint does not work. Consider changing ACTIVE to

```
ACTIVE SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CHECK (ACTIVE BETWEEN 0 AND 1),
UNIQUE (START, COMPANYID, ACTIVE)
```

Though I'm not convinced that a certain COMPANYID at a particular START can be both ACTIVE and NOT ACTIVE, but then I don't know your business.

EDIT:
Given the new info in the question, something like this might be possible (I don't have access to the docs for system i right now, so I don't know whether generated columns, or constraints on expressions exists)

```
create table t 
( a int not null generated always as identity
, x int not null
, y int
, z int not null generated always as ( 
    case when y is null then -1*a else y end 
)
, unique(x,z)
, check (y is null or y = 1)
);

insert into t(x) values (1); -- ok
insert into t(x) values (1); -- ok
insert into t(x,y) values (1,1); -- ok
insert into t(x,y) values (1,1); -- fails because of constraint violation.
```

Comment: I'd thought it was system-agnostic so I left the tag off. Apparently not. Suffice it to say, it works with my version of DB2.

Comment: What version of Db2 are you using?

Comment: Version 7 Revision 1

Comment: I assume this is AS400 (or whatever it is called nowadays:-). Anyhow, can a company at a given start be both ACTIVE=0 and ACTIVE=null?

Comment: Yes. You can only have at most one ACTIVE, but can have any number of records where ACTIVE is null. And yeah, AS400.

Comment: @ybercube, not sure I follow. According to the fiddle above, 4 DBMS would violate the constraint, 4 DBMS would not.

Comment: I also tested on my local Db2 11.5: `db2 "create table t (x int not null, y int, unique(x,y))"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0542N  The column named "Y" cannot be a column of a primary key or unique 
key constraint because it can contain null values.  SQLSTATE=42831
`

Comment: Hm, I would say that the rule is that a constraint must not evaluate to FALSE, but when NULL enters the scene, they usually evaluate to NULL, and that is therefore ok. I would not say that it is ignored

Comment: Note that Db2 for LUW will let you create a unique _index_ with a nullable column, but that column will be allowed to contain only one null value (i.e. for the purposes of determining uniqueness all null values are considered equal). Same behaviour on IBM i.